# How to call arrow function in another arrow function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Hey I have three functions in my javascript file like this

token.js

```
const function1 = async (token) => {
  .....
};

const function2 = async(token, permission) => {
    // I want to call function1 here like
    function1(token);
};

module.exports = { function1, function2 }
```

In `function2` I want to call function it is giving me an error `function1 is not a function`

Does anyone know how to resolve this ?

Comment: Could you post some more relevant code? maybe something important is missing here.

Comment: I ran this code it works on my machine, are both function is in same file or you exporting it from somewhere else

Comment: I am exporting like module.exports = {
  function1, function2
}

Answer (score 3):

It should be working. Check this: [working functions](https://es6console.com/jfrww3sc/)

```js
'use strict';

const function1 = async (token) => {
  console.log(token);
};

const function2 = async(token, permission) => {
    // I want to call function1 here like
    function1(token);
};

function2('apple','ball');
```

Comment: function1(token); in function2 is giving me an error

Comment: @NSharma, i am calling function2 which calls function1.

Comment: it says `_function1` is not a function

Comment: _function1 ? your definition of function1 doesnot have _ as a prefix though. It works on es6 environment itself, which i have included in the answer as well

Comment: I am exporting like module.exports = { function1, function2 }

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way you importing/exporting the functions:
I changed your code a little and it works:

```
const function1 = async (token) => {
  console.log(token)
};

const function2 = async  (token) => {
    // I want to call function1 here like
     //console.log(token)
    function1(token);
};

export const f= {  function1, function2 }
```

and code that using the function:

```
import {f}  from './funcs.ts'

f.function2('ooo')
```

look at this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/UoiQdOKEZGN9eNzXnqPk?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution to use function1 from say `file1.js` into function2 which is in another different JS file - say `file2.js`

> file1.js

```
const function1 = async (token) => {
      .....
};

export { function1 }
```

And inside

> file2.js

```
import { function1 } from './src/utils/file1' 

{
...other stuff
function1(token);
}
```